# How to handle constraint violation when using Spring Data JPA with Oracle Identity column and a different column as primary key?

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Spring JPA with Oracle DB : Our database schema has a table with an Oracle Identity column (id) and another column as a primary key uuid. The problem I am running into is when using `save` operation on the JPARepository.

```
    id                  NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
    UUID                VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                                      NOT NULL ENABLE,
    DOC_TYPE            VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                                      NOT NULL ENABLE,
    DESCRIPTION         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)                                      NOT NULL ENABLE,
    PRIMARY KEY (UUID)
```

My Entity class looks like this

```
public class Document {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "UUID", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private String uuid;

    @Column(name = "DOC_TYPE", nullable = false)
    private String docType;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", nullable = false)
    private String description;
}
```

When I call the `save` operation on the Spring Data JPA repository using a transient entity, I get a constraint violation when the transient object being saved has a uuid that matches the uuid of a row in the database. Ideally I would like the transient entity to be merged with the persisted one.

Database entity vs Incoming Entity

```
id: 1
uuid: sadwe-1232-123
docType: Invoice
description: Vendor inc.
```

```
id: 
uuid: sadwe-1232-123
docType: Receipt
description: Vendor inc.
```

I understand why we are seeing the constraint violation - since the uuid is not set as the @Id property for the Document class spring does not realize both the entities are the same and tries to insert a new entity. Is there an elegant solution to this problem other than me mapping the properties from the transient entity to the persisted entity and then saving the persisted entity?

Comment: If you want to update the existing entity then you should set the id=1 (in above example).

Comment: *Is there an elegant solution to this problem?* Yes, remove the `UUID` column and use only `Id`.